# Oppo Realme 1 is not detecting in android studio 3 for Debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, oppo

My device Oppo Realme1 is not detecting in my Android Studio 3.0.1 for debugging. I search a lot of things in web, tried to installed few software's for adb. But didn't find the official oem driver link. My USB debugging is on, also I can able to browse phone docs in my pc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried connecting in file transfer mode ?

Comment: Yes. I selected File Transfer also inside " Select USB Configuration" I tried selecting MTP & PTP also charging, all didn't worked for me. I can able to debug MI devices

Comment: check with `adb devices` command whether it is getting detected or not

Comment: My problem is resolved. I just installed PdaNet software it worked. Thanks